# How to define global error handler in RTK Query

Tags: error-handling, rtk-query

I have api defined in RTK query in a "standard" way like

```js
export const myApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "myApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://some-url",
  }) as BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, APIError>,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getX: builder.query<ResponseX, null>({
      query: () => ({
        url: "getX",
      }),
      async onQueryStarted: (args, { queryFulfilled }) => {
        try {
          const { data } = await queryFulfilled
        } catch (err) {
          // handle error for getX here
        }
      }
    }),
    getY: builder.query<ResponseY, null>({
      query: () => ({
        url: "getY",
      }),
      async onQueryStarted: (args, { queryFulfilled }) => {
        try {
          const { data } = await queryFulfilled
        } catch (err) {
          // handle error for getY here
        }
      }
    }),
    ...
  })
})
```

I know how to handle errors for individual endpoints, but is there a way to define a global error handler capturing errors from all endpoints in one single handler/function?

Comment: Doesn't `fetchBaseQuery` handle that already? Or are you referring to other non-network-related errors? Can you [edit] to clarify the issue or what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: According to the documentation for `fetchBaseQuery` at https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#signature, I don't see any argument within `FetchBaseQueryArgs` that would allow me to add handling error.

I want to react to any error occurring from any endpoint in `myApi` in my application, and I thought there would be a single place where I can define it which would apply to all endpoints. Something similar to interceptors in axios for example.

Comment: I meant that `fetchBaseQuery` ***already*** handles errors, though you *could* create a [custom base query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#customizing-queries-with-basequery) to handle them differently. This only handles network-related errors though, you haven't clarified *what* errors you are referring to.

Comment: I've updated my example with handling errors for `getX` and `getY` endpoints. This way, they are handled in `onQueryStarted` callbacks in each endpoint. I was wondering if there is a way to define global handler that would handle both these errors in one place. Imagine I have 10 endpoints defined in `myApi`, I don't want to have 10 `onQueryStarted` duplicating pretty much the same code.

Comment: You could write a single `onQueryStarted` function and use that instead of the anonymous functions in each endpoint. Do you need to handle endpoint errors differently, or would just one single `catch` in a single `onQueryStarted` function really handle them all for you?

Comment: Yes, one single catch is fine for me - I just want to show the error in a toast / snackbar in my application.

Answer (score 6):

If all you want is for each query/mutation to have the "same" error response handling you could define a custom `onQueryStarted` function that awaits the query/mutation to settle and trigger the toast upon errors.

```js
const onQueryStartedErrorToast = (args, { queryFulfilled }) => {
  try {
    await queryFulfilled;
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error here, dispatch toast message
  }
};
```

```js
export const myApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "myApi",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://some-url",
  }) as BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, APIError>,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getX: builder.query<ResponseX, null>({
      query: () => ({
        url: "getX",
      }),
      onQueryStarted: onQueryStartedErrorToast
    }),
    getY: builder.query<ResponseY, null>({
      query: () => ({
        url: "getY",
      }),
      onQueryStarted: onQueryStartedErrorToast
    }),
    ...
  }),
});
```

This pattern would work until you have an endpoint that you want to toast errors for ***and*** do other things. Here you could write one-off `onQueryStarted` handlers that do exactly what you want.

If it's the case that no matter the endpoint you want to toast errors, then you could write your own [custom base query function](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#customizing-queries-with-basequery) that reads any errors as the "pass through" and issue the toasts.

Example:

```js
const baseQuery = (baseQueryOptions) => async (args, api, extraOptions) => {
  const result = await fetchBaseQuery(baseQueryOptions)(args, api, extraOptions);

  if (result.error) {
    // dispatch toast message
  }

  return result;
};
```

```js
export const myApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: "myApi",
  baseQuery: baseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://some-url",
  }) as BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, APIError>,
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getX: builder.query<ResponseX, null>({
      query: () => ({
        url: "getX",
      }),
      async onQueryStarted: (args, { queryFulfilled }) => {
        try {
          const { data } = await queryFulfilled;
        } catch (err) {
          // handle error for getX here
        }
      }
    }),
    getY: builder.query<ResponseY, null>({
      query: () => ({
        url: "getY",
      }),
    }),
    ...
  }),
});
```

Comment: in your example, there is no dispatch in fetchBaseQuery, how to call dispatch ?
 if (result.error) {
    // dispatch toast message
  }

Comment: @MrSpecial `dispatch` is available via the [`BaseQueryAPI`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi#basequery), e.g. the `api` arg. The code would be something like `api.dispatch(toast(/* error message */));`.

Comment: This seems like a common pattern you'd want to account for with RTK Query, I searched through the docs and it was never apparent to do it this way until I stumbled on your answer. Something as simple as waiting for a mutation to complete (success / error) and react to it. React-Query got rid of the 'onSuccess' for queries, but kept it for mutations for these types of situations. RTK Query docs feel overly convoluted comparatively

Answer (score 2):

You can create this middleware function in your store redux and get all data from errors and slice.

```js
import {
  Middleware,
  MiddlewareAPI,
  configureStore,
  isRejected,
  isRejectedWithValue,
} from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import ui from "./slices/ui"; // for example

export const rtkQueryErrorLogger: Middleware =
  (api: MiddlewareAPI) => (next) => (action) => {
    // isRejectedWithValue Or isRejected
    if (isRejected(action)) {
      console.log(action) // get all data from rejected request
      if (action.payload?.status === 401) {
        console.log("error auth");
      }
    }

    return next(action);
  };

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    ui: ui,
  },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(rtkQueryErrorLogger),
});
 
export default store;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a middlewar like:

```
const authMiddleware =
  ({ dispatch }: any) =>
  (next: any) =>
  (action: any) => {
    if (action.type.includes("Mutation")) {
      if (action.type.endsWith("fulfilled")) {
        // Successful mutation
        const successMessage =
          action?.payload?.response?.message || "Succuss!";
        toast.success(successMessage);
      } else if (action.type.endsWith("rejected")) {
        // Failed mutation
        const errorMessage =
          action?.payload?.data?.message || "Unkown Error accourred.";
        toast.error(errorMessage);
      }
    }

    return next(action);
  };
```